# Change the clock svg to another svg in Material UI X Timepicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, timepicker

I am using the Material UI x time-picker component in my app. I would like to change the clock SVG in the component to a custom SVG (a Chevron). I read that I need to use the props components. But what is the component called? I tried with the testid ClockIcon but that was not successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is this:

```
<TimePicker
    label="Time"
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
    components={{
      OpenPickerIcon: SearchIcon //  Replace with your icon 
    }}
  />
```

For example I have  imported the `SearchIcon` to use it as an example to replace the default one.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Where did you find the name of the component? For future reference...

Comment: @Harry_C, that's a good point. Unfortunately I couldn't find a guide that will have all the info. The way I trouble shout it, is that I knew that is a 'components' property (as you also mentioned), then inspect at the names of the icons and after that is was a matter of trial and error. Keep in mind that 'OpenPickerIcon' is a common case for Textfields with an icon that opens a popup. If I find find something like a complete guide I will post it here.